# Paypal IPN not responding at all

Tags: php, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

Anybody having this problem? Suddenly paypal is not returning POST data to the notify_url. Array is completely empty and it happens when payment is made through **new paypal checkout system**.

[image]

---

Below is the final page after payment is made. When I click continue booking, it should have redirected to notify_url with POST data for validation and stuff but data is an empty array.

[image]

My request code is listed below. Can anybody please take a look at it and tell me whether some variable is missing or i am doing something wrong?

```
<form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="ayaz.a_1286483626_biz@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <!-- the next three need to be created -->    
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://system1.smanager.net/SM/lib/booking_system/response.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://system1.smanager.net/SM/lib/booking_system/paypal_ipn.php?cancelled=true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://system1.smanager.net/SM/lib/booking_system/response.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />

    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="toolkit-php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Continue Back to Booking System" />

    <!-- Payment Page Information -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Comments" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cs" value="" />


    <!-- Product Information -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="TestProduct" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.23" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234" />
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="" />

    <input type="hidden" name="os1" value="" />

    <!-- Shipping and Misc Information -->
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="somedata" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="" />

    <!-- Customer Information -->

    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="ayaz" />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="alavi" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="Address" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="abc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="ayaz.a_1286483582_per@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="" />

    <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="" />

</form>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: For reference, Paypal doesn't 'redirect' to the notify_url.  It just posts order and invoice data there once the payment has been approved; the user never sees that post.

Comment: yeah but I need that data to confirm payment by the user. Do you know why paypal is sending empty POST? Also I need alternate form for sending request because this form might be buggy.

Comment: @cHao thanks for this info...This is the actual reason I am not seeing post data because they are just sending post request in the background process not as a result of transaction

Answer (score 1):

I have also face same problem.

Please set the following settings in Your business account.

In Website Payment Preferences

=> Auto Return: On

=> Set Return URL

=> Payment Data Transfer: On.

Please try this, this may help you.

All the best.

Kanji